# Do I need 4.5 hosting for a Visual Studio 2012 project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, hosting, asp.net-4.5

Do I need 4.5 hosting for a Visual Studio 2012 project? I am using 2012 SQL Server as well. Does this require 4.5 framework for hosting?

Comment: depends what framework version you targeted with VS2012....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not require .NET 4.5 - You can choose what version of the framework you need by going to Project -> Properties. SQL Server seems to rely only on .NET 4 (NOT .NET 4.5)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the settings of your project.  In VS2012, in the Project --> Properties dialog, you can set the target framework version.  Depending on what you're doing you may or may not need the full 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless your project is using .NET Framework 4.5